# HTML 5 Mobile Web App Workflows? --- (Advanced Questions)

Tags: extjs, cordova, single-page-application, mobile-application, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm beginning to build my first mobile web app and I'll be using a combination of html5, css3, javascript, and at the end I'll be wrapping it up with Phone Gap (Cordova) then deploying it out to both the Android and iPhone marketplaces. I won't be using anything else like java, php, or c#.. This is strictly front-end based, so the questions below are in retrospect to the this and will play a big role in creating my mobile workflow.

As I'm fairly seasoned in the above front-end technologies, mobile apps are a different world, which leaves me with some questions...

**Mobile App Questions (Workflow)**

**1.)** Should I build it with 1 page (single page app) or multiple pages? I know I could us an AJAX solution here to give the "1 page" look/feel, but what's the smartest solution?

**2.)** Ad placement, in retrospect to 1 page/multi-page apps, I assume multiple pages would be a smarter choice? The more refreshes the better for CPM or is this considered bad practice? ...or can I achieve ad refreshes with smart AJAX placement inside a 1 page app?

**3.)** Gestures vs. buttons and css - I've been building responsive websites for the last year and have noticed that I can achieve a lot of *effects* with css alone (i.e. hover, focus, active, overflow... to name a few). When is it necessary to use gestures? [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/examples/events.html) seems to be doing a pretty good job of these effects and I'll definitely be taking a closer look at that plugin.

**4.)** CSS3 Animations vs. Jquery Animations vs. WebGL Animations - What's best? According to [this link](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/), CSS 3 wins... But I've heard about css3 REALLY slowing things down (i.e. using border-radius). What's safe to use for a mobile app?

**5.)** The "back" button on android phone, I assume it's used just like a web browsers back button.. So if I build a "1 page app" that could be a bad choice if a user clicks "back" then immediately exits your application. I'm sure I could use an alert box to question the user first, just curious on if their is any recommended solutions?

**6.)** The "settings/options" button on an Android phone, I assume it will do nothing if I don't tell it to... But, if I wanted to tell it to do something how could I?

**7.)** File System - What's the best way to access the file system (opening media, saving media, saving media to "custom app folder name", sharing media to facebooks/twitter/instagram, accessing contacts, texting, email, etc...), Since I'm only using front-end technologies, what's the best ways to handle this? It seems like I've read somewhere that [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) and/or [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/) have JS solutions for this.., what's your preferred way and how does it actually work?

**8.)** Testing - When I start implementing all of these "File System" commands, how on earth do I test this? I'm of course coding on a computer, Will Android and IOS emulators really do the trick or will I have to manually load my mobile app to a server and check? Is their a way to test locally with my phone? (that'd be cool :)

**9.)** Performance - I know performance is key with any application but ESPECIALLY mobile apps. I use jQuery (hey, I'm a UI guy :), and I know I'll be using a few other smart scripts so mobile phones will play nicely ([SouthStreet Progressive Enhancement Workflow](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Southstreet))... but how much is TO MUCH?? In the future if I wanted to use more powerful js libraries such as knowckout.js or angular.js, how would this effect the performance of a REAL html 5 mobile app?

These are the questions that are running through my mind right now. If anyone has some good knowledge of a tutorial that explains these things or if anyone can point me in a good direction I'd really appreciate it! I also hope that these questions will help other poor lost souls like myself ;)

[image]

Comment: You can use Jquery Mobile, few of your answers you will get there

Comment: The South Street Workflow that I mentioned in question 9 and jQuery Mobile are in fact the same thing and made by the same person! (Scott Jehl). South Street is filled with all of the juicy stuff that's in JQuery Mobile but broken apart into little chunks to allow developers full customization! I like having that sort of freedom when designing/developing, thanks for bringing that up ;)